# Expand a macro with parameters in tabular head

Tags: tables, expansion

My eventual goal is to create my own tabular-like environment in which all entries are in math-mode by default, let's call it `fancytable`. (One requirement is that the first column be separated from the others by a line, but that shouldn't be the main problem.)

In [Math mode in tabular without having to use $...$ everywhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112576) I found how to approach the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ >{$}c<{$} | >{$}c<{$} >{$}c<{$} }
    x & x^2 & x^3\\
    y & y^2 & y^4
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

but this is not what I'm looking for. (Note I am including `tabularx` because I need it for other purposes, I think it is relevant to mention.) The tabular may become large (say 15 columns) so writing `>{$}c<{$}` every time would be tedious. Also, some day I might change my mind and choose another lay-out, and changing all tables isn't really a thing I'm looking forward to. That's why I try to make it an environment.
Recently I asked how to copy and print a string a few times, in [A command which concatenates a string an arbitrary number of times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199113). So currently I have a command `\repeatstring` available and I expect to need it as in `\repeatstring{5}{>{$}c<{$}}`. (I have included its current definition below)
The first thing I tried is something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
% definition of \repeatstring left out, see below
\newenvironment{fancytable}[1]%
    {\begin{tabular}{ >{$}c<{$} | \repeatstring{#1}{>{$}c<{$}} } }
    {\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\begin{fancytable}{2} % the argument of fancytable is 1 less than the desired number of columns
    x & x^2 & x^3\\
    y & y^2 & y^4
\end{fancytable}
\end{document}
```

but `tabular` does not accept arbitrary commands in its header. I read trough [How do I expand a macro into a tabular head?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12234) and tried to adapt the answers given there. Meanwhile I figured out that I should somehow expand `\repeatstring` before `tabular` sees what's going on in its head. I think defining a new `columntype` every time a `fancytable` is created is not a good thing to do (I fail to do it anyway, getting the same error as with the above approach). Some tries:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
% definition of \repeatstring left out, see below
\newcommand\buildtabularhead{}
\newenvironment{fancytable}[1]%
    {%
    \renewcommand\buildtabularhead{ >{$}c<{$} | \repeatstring{#1}{>{$}c<{$}} }%
    \expandafter\tabular\expandafter{\buildtabularhead}}
    {\endtabular}
\begin{document}
\begin{fancytable}{2}
    x & x^2 & x^3\\
    y & y^2 & y^4
\end{fancytable}
\end{document}
```

(based on Matthew Leingang's answer) but I keep getting

> Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\repeatstring): `c' used.

as usual. The same with Bruno Le Floch's answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
% definition of \repeatstring left out, see below
\makeatletter
    \newcolumntype{\expand}{}
    \long\@namedef{NC@rewrite@\string\expand}{\expandafter\NC@find}
\makeatother
\newcommand\mypream{}
\newenvironment{fancytable}[1]%
    {%
    \renewcommand\mypream{ >{$}c<{$} | \repeatstring{#1}{>{$}c<{$}} }%
    \begin{tabular}{\expand\mypream}}
    {\endtabular}
\begin{document}
\begin{fancytable}{2}
    x & x^2 & x^3\\
    y & y^2 & y^4
\end{fancytable}
\end{document}
```

I really don't know what to do. I read [When to use \edef, \noexpand, and \expandafter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451) but didn't achieve to use `\expandafter` of `\edef` in the right way. I always and up with

> Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\repeatstring or \edef or \expandafter or \setcounter): `c' used.

`\setcounter` comes from my current definition of `\repeatstring` when I expand it:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{countdown}
\newcommand\concathere{}
\newcommand\repeatstring[2]{
    \setcounter{countdown}{#1}
    \renewcommand\concathere{}
    \whileboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\thecountdown}{>}{0}}}{
        \addtocounter{countdown}{-1}
        \appto\concathere{#2}
        }
    \concathere
    }
```

Comment: At some point a command appeared here (dissappeared by now) which gave the solution `\begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$} | * {#1} {>{$}c<{$}} }`. This works. Perhaps I shouldn't spent that much time trying, since some smart command may solve it. >_<

Comment: I was just about to suggest the `*` operator :-) Please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: I would be interested to see how to solve the issue anyway ;-)

Comment: essentially the only difference between the `array` and `tabular` environments is that the entries are in math mode, why not simply use an array? `c` in array and `>$c<$` in `tabular` are the same thing.

Comment: I did try with arrays but back then something went wrong, seems like now everything works fine. It could have been a typo.

Comment: @barto In any case, the package `array` lets you define new column types, for instance you could define `M` to be `>{$}c<{$}`, and then use `\begin{tabular}{MMMMMM}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best solution to a simply 'repeat *n*-times' in a `tabular` preamble is indeed to use the  `*` syntax as in [barto's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199241). However, if you do want to use a macro containing the preamble for some reason, using [Bruno's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14460) to [How do I expand a macro into a tabular head?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12234/how-do-i-expand-a-macro-into-a-tabular-head), then the important thing to do is to make sure it contains *exactly* the preamble text. That requires a definition of `\repeatstring` which is expandable and the use of an `\edef`-like expansion of the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\repeatstring}{mm}
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
    \newcolumntype{\expand}{}
    \long\@namedef{NC@rewrite@\string\expand}{\expandafter\NC@find}
\makeatother
\newcommand\mypream{}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{fancytable}[1]%
    {%
    \protected@edef\mypream{ >{$}c<{$} | \repeatstring{#1}{>{$}c<{$}} }%
    \begin{tabular}{\expand\mypream}}
    {\end{tabular}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{fancytable}{2}
    x & x^2 & x^3\\
    y & y^2 & y^4
\end{fancytable}
\end{document}
```

In the above, I've used an `expl3` based expandable repeat function to define `\repeatstring` (much the same as [egeg's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199132) to [A command which concatenates a string an arbitrary number of times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199113/a-command-which-concatenates-a-string-an-arbitrary-number-of-times)), which means that when `\protected@edef` is applied `\mypream` ends up with definition `>{$}c<{$} | >{$}c<{$}>{$}c<{$}`, *i.e.* exactly what is needed in the `tabular` preamble.

All of this is needed as `array` avoids any expansion of the `tabular` preamble. Thus if you do

```
\renewcommand\mypream{ >{$}c<{$} | \repeatstring{#1}{>{$}c<{$}} }%
```

what `array` sees is exactly that: not a string of repeated `>{$}c<{$}` entries but the token `\repeatstring`, which is does not know (and so raises an error).

Comment: putting `\expand\romannumeral-\`0` just before `\repeatstring` also works (well, except that `\repeatstring` was not defined).  Admittedly, that's hardly something to recommend :-).

Answer (score 5):

Replacing `c` by `>$c<$` in a tabular as requested here is basically defining the `array` environment. Also there is no harm in declaring more columns than used, so the number of columns argument isn't really needed, just declare a large number (50 here)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newenvironment{fancytable}
    {$\begin{array}{c| * {50} {c} }  }
    {\end{array}$}
\begin{document}

\begin{fancytable}
    x & x^2 & x^3\\
    y & y^2 & y^4
\end{fancytable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Daniel for the suggestion, no need of `\repeatstring` here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newenvironment{fancytable}[1]%
    {\begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$} | * {#1} {>{$}c<{$}} }  }
    {\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\begin{fancytable}{2}
    x & x^2 & x^3\\
    y & y^2 & y^4
\end{fancytable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is another approach: direct usage of `\halign` primitive. Note the following feature of `\halign`:

```
\halign{first:#. && rep:# \cr
         a& b& c& d& e \cr
         u& v& w& x& y \cr}
```

creates:

```
 first:a. rep:b rep:c rep:d rep:e
 first:u. rep:v rep:w rep:x rep:y
```

In other words: you needn't to declare all columns in declaration part of `\halign`. If there are more actual columns then the processing returns to the `&&` mark and the declaration part is read again and again...

The implementation of your `fancytable` can look like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{fancytable}
   {\vbox\bgroup\offinterlineskip \let\\=\cr
    \halign\bgroup$##$\ \vrule height2ex depth1ex &&\ $##$\ \cr}
   {\crcr\egroup\egroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{fancytable} 
    x & x^2 & x^3\\
    y & y^2 & y^4
\end{fancytable}

\end{document}
```

No special package you needs. The first column is processed by

```
$##$\ \vrule height2ex depth1ex
```

declaration part and *arbitrary number of* next columns are processed by

```
\ $##$\
```

Sometimes, it is usable to know the TeX primitives.