# xsim, babel and tikzcd clash: quotation marks

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, tikz-cd, xsim

I'm trying to write a simple commutative diagram like `A \arrow[r, "f"] & B` but I can't do it inside xsim's exercise environment (the combination of the exercise environment with the babel package, tikz package and quotation marks doesn't work).

Despite having tried everythting, I could only narrow down the problem. Could you help me with the last step of the puzzle?

PS: I leave a minimal example below of what worked and didn't work. Thank you for your help!

```
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}

%With quotation marks, it works outside the exercise environment:
   $\begin{tikzcd} 
   A \arrow[r, "f"] & B
   \end{tikzcd}$ 

%Without quotation marks, it works inside the exercise environment (with ampersand replacement):
   \begin{exercise}
   $\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&] 
   A \arrow[r] \& B
   \end{tikzcd}$
   \end{exercise}

%With quotation marks, it doesn't work inside the exercise environment:
   \begin{exercise}
   $\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&] 
   A \arrow[r, "f"] \& B
   \end{tikzcd}$
   \end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same problem as in

- [Problem bringing the commutative diagram inside the question and answer frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/625281/16595) and
- [\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzcd} hasn't any effect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/601552/16595)

Here are three solutions:

1. Use the **`use-files` class option**.

   This will write additional files for every `exercise` environment (though there are options to tidy up your document folder) but it allows you to use both `"` and `&` as if the CD were written in the normal part of the document.
2. Use

   ```
   \AtBeginEnvironment{exercise}{\shorthandoff{"}}
   ```

   to **switch off the `"` shorthand inside the `exercise` environment**:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{xsim}
   \usepackage{tikz-cd}
   \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
   \usetikzlibrary{babel}
   \AtBeginEnvironment{exercise}{\shorthandoff{"}}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{exercise}
   % Need to use \babelshorthand{"-} instead of "-
   \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
   A \arrow[r, "f"] \& B
   \end{tikzcd}
   \end{exercise}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   That's not really bad unless you need to use the shorthands often inside an `exercise` environment.
3. As an alternative, here's an implementation that does *not* need to turn off the `"` shorthand but **uses `'` instead of `"`**.

   This is a TikZ-CD only solution and it also essentially disables the TikZ shorthand `'` for `swap` inside the argument for `\arrow` but not as part of a label (as in `'f''`).

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{xsim}
   \usepackage{tikz-cd}
   \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
   \usetikzlibrary{babel}
   \makeatletter
   \tikzcdset{
     every label/.prefix code=% disable ' first char again to allow ' = swap
       \pgfkeyslet{/handlers/first char syntax/\expandafter\meaning\string'}%
                  \pgfutil@undefined,
     execute before arrows={%
       \pgfkeyssetvalue{/handlers/first char syntax/\expandafter\meaning\string'}
                       {\tikzcd@forward@singlequotes}}}
   \def\tikzcd@forward@singlequotes#1{\tikzcd@forward@@singlequotes#1\pgf@stop}
   \def\tikzcd@forward@@singlequotes'#1'#2\pgf@stop{%
     \tikzcd@forward@quotes{"{#1}"#2}}
   \makeatother

   \begin{document}
   \begin{exercise}
   \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
   A \arrow[r, 'f''] \& B
   \end{tikzcd}
   \end{exercise}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]