# What's the maximum value that can be displayed by \Roman

Tags: counters

Apparently a counter can store [up to `2^31-1` (e-TeX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/270535/28808).  But if I want to typeset that counter using `\Roman`, what's the maximum I can display?

Comment: 2^31-1 (although it doesn't try too hard to use a historically accurate representation)

Comment: This depends on the font, I would say. `M` is wider than `L`, in most cases, `D` is narrower than `M`, so there might be an optimum for the `\textwidth`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see there's some flexibility in the historical approaches (linked in my comment under your answer).

Comment: By the way, what set me thinking of this was [Golf my Shakespeare quote references](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123693/44821)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{zz}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{zz}{2147483647}
 \Roman{zz}



\end{document}
```

Roman works for the full range, but you need a very wide page.

```
Overfull \hbox (24217.02405pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 8--9
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
...
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMDCXLVII
```

Comment: Is this what they mean by the "width in ems"?

Comment: So after `MMMCMXCIX` (or   `MMMMCMXCIX` if you like) this takes the simple approach rather than any of the alternatives such as using [`$\bar\mathrm{X}$` or `\=X` for 10 000 (maths/text modes)](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/cajorinot.pdf) or the multiplicative version in @Schweinebacke's answer.  This is universal and simple I suppose.

Comment: @ChrisH yes it just adds `m`  (which is used as a useful loop generator in certain trick constructs) see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199162/1090

Answer (score 5):

Try it out:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{maxroman}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{maxroman}{0}% use the initial value you like (e.g. 2147483640)
\makeatletter
\@whilenum \value{maxroman}<\maxdimen\do{%
  \stepcounter{maxroman}%
  \typeout{Trying \themaxroman}%
  \themaxroman=\Roman{maxroman}\par
}
\end{document}
```

;-)

Nevertheless large Roman numbers with aphostrophus (e.g. `IↃↃↃↃ` for 500.000), vinculum or multiplication (e.g. `D•M`) as usually used are not supported by (La)TeX.

Comment: I am sorry.  You posted your answer to the wrong question.  I think you meant to post it here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122116/how-to-prolong-compilation-time-while-engaging-in-leisure-activities.  `;^)` By the way, you hung my computer!

Comment: Counting to `2^31-1` could take a while...a very long while.  How many years do you still have before you?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Hopefully several more than my computer.

Comment: I considered this experiment, but with the level of expertise here thought there would be a documented value somewhere.

Comment: @ChrisH For a documented value see David's answer or simply start the experiment with a higher value (e.g. `\maxdimen-1`) or turn it (start with `\maxdimen` and loop down to 1).