# String multiplication possible in LaTeX as in Python?

Tags: strings, text-manipulation

I'd like to set a string multiplication in LaTeX in order to **print *n* times a specific string or character**.

Just like in Python one would do :

```
print('mystring' * 3)
```

to get `mystringmystringmystring`.

How do I do this in LaTeX?

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199113/a-command-which-concatenates-a-string-an-arbitrary-number-of-times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can include the `pgffor` package, then it is as easy as doing `\foreach \i in {1,...,3}{mystring}`. For easier use, it can be wrapped in a command:

```
\newcommand{\repeatn}[2]{\foreach \i in {1, ..., #1} {#2}}

Usage: \repeatn{3}{mystring}
```

Comment: Waww fairly simple ! Thanks @gjulianm! it'll simplify a lot my document !

Answer (score 6):

Here's the mandatory L3 approach with `\prg_replicate`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_replicate:nn {11}{na}~Batman!
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks @Paulo Cereda I'll see for putting it into a newcommand :-)

Answer (score 2):

Without any additional packages, you can use the `\loop` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{tmp}
\newcommand{\strmult}[2]{\setcounter{tmp}{0}\loop\stepcounter{tmp}{#1}\ifnum\value{tmp}<#2\repeat}

\begin{document}

\strmult{foo}{4}\strmult{bar}{5}

\end{document}
```

[image]